# Connection String in C#.Net

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, connection-string

//*SQL PART*

**Line 1** : `string dd = "Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename="C:\Users\HEX\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\cventry_address_book_0.1\cventry_address_book_0.1\addressbook.mdf";Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True";`

**Line 2** :`SqlConnection sqlconobj = new SqlConnection(dd);`

**Line 3**: `sqlconobj.Open();`

---------**Errors Output**------------

> Unexpected character'\'

Comment: checkout [string literals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) in .net and read about verbatim string

Answer (score 3):

In C# the backslash character has special meaning.
You need to double it or prefix your entire string with the Verbatim character @
And there is no need to put a double quote before and after the file name.
Formatting rules (the ending semicolon) allows spaces in path or file name for the AttachDbFileName

```
 string dd = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=" + 
             @"C:\Users\HEX\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\" + 
             @"Projects\cventry_address_book_0.1\cventry_address_book_0.1" + 
             @"\addressbook.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True";
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
string dd = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=""C:\Users\HEX\Documents\Visual Studio008\Projects\cventry_address_book_0.1\cventry_address_book_0.1\addressbook.mdf"";Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True";
```

You need to escape the string by using the `@` character.  Alternative you could replace single `\`'s with `\\`.

Comment: Even if you use `@`, the quotes still need to be escaped using `""`.

Comment: @JLRishe have you tried? The ending semicolon removes the ambiguity of normal paths

Comment: @Steve The quotes may not be necessary at all; I'm not sure on that point and that's not what my comment was referring to. What I can say for sure is that Darren's answer was invalid (as in, would not compile) the way he entered it, because it had unescaped quotes midstring.

Comment: Never had the chance to test with a Sql Server db, but I can assure you that a simple Access database placed in a path with spaces don't need any _double quote_

Answer (score 1):

You should escape the string by prefixing it with the `@` character. Also you should wrap your SqlConnection instance in a using statement:

```
string dd = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=""C:\Users\HEX\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\cventry_address_book_0.1\cventry_address_book_0.1\addressbook.mdf"";Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True";
using (SqlConnection sqlconobj = new SqlConnection(dd))
{
    sqlconobj.Open();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need escape the `\` character.
Use this:

```
string dd = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename="C:\Users\HEX\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\cventry_address_book_0.1\cventry_address_book_0.1\addressbook.mdf";Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True";
```

More: [String literals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

```
string dd = "Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=\"C:\\Users\\HEX\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2008\\Projects\\cventry_address_book_0.1\\cventry_address_book_0.1\\addressbook.mdf\";Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True";
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be your query connection string

```
string dd = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=" + 
                            @"C:\Users\HEX\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\cventry_address_book_0.1\cventry_address_book_0.1\addressbook.mdf" 
                            + ";Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True";
```